# Variable with name `None`

Tags: python

I need to have a variable with name `None`:

```
class QAbstractPrintDialog(QDialog):
    None = int() # QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintDialogOption enum
    PrintToFile = int() # QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintDialogOption enum
    PrintSelection = int() # QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintDialogOption enum
    ...
```

But:

> syntax error: cannot assign to None

I need the name to be `None`. I thought this will work:

```
QAbstractPrintDialog.None = int() # QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintDialogOption enum
```

But it didn't. Is there a workaround to not have a syntax error?
Solutions like setattr don't work for me - this code will be parsed to extract classes, functions, arguments, etc.

Python 2.6, 2.7

**EDIT:**

I am helping a guy to write pseudo-Python modules which contain description of Qt classes. `QAbstractPrintDialog` is one of the classes and it has `enum QAbstractPrintDialog::PrintDialogOption` (http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractprintdialog.html). One of the enums is None. I can easily reference a `None` attribute via `QAbstractPrintDialog.None` but i can not set it. `int()` means the type of the attribute.

See here: http://scummos.blogspot.com/2011/06/kdevelop-python-language-support-plugin.html

Comment: Why do you actually **need** that?. why dont 'none' or 'nil'?

Comment: Assiging None = int() is just bare nonsense and absolutely worst-style programming

Comment: I am helping a guy to write pseudo-Python modules which contain description of Qt classes. `QAbstractPrintDialog` is one of the classes and it has `enum QAbstractPrintDialog::PrintDialogOption` (http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractprintdialog.html). One of the enums is None. I can easily reference a `None` attribute via `QAbstractPrintDialog.None` but i can not set it. `int()` means the type of the attribute.

Comment: http://scummos.blogspot.com/2011/06/basic-list-content-type-support-in.html

Answer (score 10):

In python `None` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name.
Quoting python documentation:

> Changed in version 2.4: Assignments to None are illegal and raise a SyntaxError.

Comment: I heard in Python 3 this has changed?

Comment: It hasn't changed in Python 3. Please explain your need to use `None` as a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. [`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) is a Python built-in constant.

To do what you are makes no more sense than:

```
class = struct
```

> "Assignments to `None` are illegal and raise a `SyntaxError`."
>   --[*The documentation*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None)

Pick another variable name: `nil`, `none`, `nothing`, `zilch`, `not_a_sausage`, `no_votes`, `zero`, `...`

I agree with you that this is a little inconsistent with other built-in constants, *viz*:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.False = True
...             self.True = False
...             self.None = 'Something'
...
  File "<stdin>", line 5
SyntaxError: assignment to None
```

...but then...

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.False = True
...             self.True = False
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.True
False
>>> f.False
True
>>> f.None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'None'
```

...of course that kind of naming and assignment could only ever lead to trouble!

Comment: i understand that `None = something` is illegal, but why `my_object.None = something` is?

Answer (score 3):

Call it something distinct like __INSTEADOF_None then strip off all instances of '_*INSTEADOF*' in a pre-processing step prior to  parsing.

Comment: It looks like that's what we'll have to do. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can try next approach:

```
>>> class A():pass

>>> a = A()
>>> a.None = 2
SyntaxError: assignment to None
>>> a.__dict__['None'] = 2
>>> a.None
2
>>> dir(a)
['None', '__doc__', '__module__']
```

But still - idea to use `None` as object field is really bad.

Comment: Thanks, is generally working. But in my particular case, the parser will not recognize the new attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It's against the rules to assign to `None` which has a very special meaning in Python. Choose a different name.